# Regex: Get first numeric data before wanted text in PHP

Tags: php

Please Anyone Help Me I have An Data For Example

djhdk3.4HF/Daysla

all data always changing

I Want To Get 3.4HF/Day

Comment: This can help you `[0-9]\.[0-9]+HF+\/Day`. You told data always changing. Is `HF/Day` also changing ?

Comment: Or, even simpler: `/\d.*/`, as shown here: https://regex101.com/r/goug9Q/1 .

Comment: Thanks I Found Solution